# PySpark Streaming updateStateByKey giving no output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, streaming

I'm running spark streaming on a simulated data stream of 4 text files with lines of bus line information for an assignment. My code works up until the application of updateStateByKey which then gives no output. I have a datastream of key,value pairs of (hour, delay) that will pprint() as intended each batch as pictured below:

[Key,Value Datastream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEkt0.png)

then when I use updateStateByKey where all it should do is sum the values each batch, I get no output aside from the initial timestamp. Again this exact code works fine on my classmates' machines.

[updateStateByKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21vGP.png)

This is the my_state_update function being called

[my_state_update function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Ris.png)

Does anyone have any ideas on whats causing this not to work on my machine? Spark core and sql have been working fine. I'm on Windows and using spyder to run the code, although I've tried running it an pycharm and from command line but still experiencing the same. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not post screenshots of code/output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), and instead paste them in blocks of code.